# Issue with changing child div style using jQuery (via class selector)

Tags: jquery, css, html

this is more curiosity question rather than a problem)

With my Rails 3 application I generate a lots of blocks, which contain div elements. One block looks like this:

```
<div class="link_div">
        <%= link_to ... %>
        <div class="ranking">
        <%= link_to ... %>
        <%= link_to ... %>
        <%= link_to ... %>
    </div>
</div>
```

And now Im trying to toggle "ranking" div visibility on mouseOVER. It wasnt so easy, cause I`m a newbie to jQuery. I was trying a lots of css accessors, but finnally I have found a solution look like this:

```
$('.link_div').hover(
      function () {
        $(this).children('.ranking').css('display','block');
      },
      function () {
        $(this).children('.ranking').css('display','none');
      }
);
```

So the question is: "Why this solution doesn`t work?":

```
$(this).children()[1].css('display','block');
```

Alert says that chilren()[1] gives me div object, but it doesn`t have .css() method. **Why?**

```
alert($(this).children()[1]) // => "[object HTMLDivElement]"
```

Comment: javascript/jQuery is the wrong technology for the functionality you are asking here. This can be done just in CSS. You will end up with clearer code that performs a lot better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you doing this in javascript? This is clearly something that belongs in css. You will get a lot clearer code, A better separation between markup, content and behavior and a huge performance gain.

**[example](http://jsfiddle.net/VJhPw/3/)**

Comment: A pure CSS solution will not work in IE6. I know it's probably not a requirement that it work in IE6 but I was just being safe with my answer. +1 for you as it is a cleaner solution if IE6 support is not required.

Comment: Anno 2011 we can safely assume ie6 support is not required unless it is explicitly specified.

Answer (score 1):

[**Here is a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YFqLW/) of a very simple way of showing/hiding the *ranking* `<div>` when hovering over the `<div class="link_div">`

The selector `$('.ranking', this)` matches all elements with class `.ranking` inside the *current element* (the [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)) and applies the [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) function to them.

As others have already answered, your problem is that you have dereferenced the jQuery object with the `[1]` and you have a raw DOM object. You need to call functions on the jQuery objects in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's an object, not a jQuery object (so, doesn't have jQuery methods/properties).

Try `$($(this).children()[1]).css('display','block');`

Or, even tidier, just remove the [1]:

`$(this).children().css('display','block');`

Answer (score 0):

`[1]` is giving you the div object, NOT a jquery object.  `.css` is a jquery method and must be used on a jquery object.

Try this instead:

```
$(this).children().eq(1).css('display','block');
```

or

```
$(this).children(":eq(1)").css('display','block');
```

and even better, use `show()` and `hide()` instead of setting the display.